# Retrieving multiple xml child node values

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I have a column of type varchar(max) populated with xml nodes and values; as an example, the column data starts with `<tag1> <tag2>value1</tag2><tag3>value2</tag3>... </tag1>`. What I need to get out of this string is "value1 value2 value3... valueN" within one cell for every row in the table using static SQL or a stored procedure. The node tree isn't always the same, sometimes the path is `<tagX><tagY>valueY</tagY>...</tagX>`.

All of my experience with shredding xml is only used to get one specific value, property, or tag, not all values while retaining the column and row count. Currently I query then loop through the result set on my product's end and shred everything, but that's no longer an option due to recent changes.

It's possible to change the column to be of type xml, but if possible I'd like to avoid having to do so.

Comment: Can you show some data and what you have tried so far ???

Comment: I can't show any data because it's PCI.

I've tried declaring an xml variable and setting it to the column data (with the intention to loop through and shred while it contained characters '<' and '>') but because I need to do this on all rows in the column I got caught on multiple values being stored in it. I've considered modify() but due to the variable nature of the node path neither delete nor value will work because I'd need to supply a set path (and delete doesn't preserve values). My experience with xml is fairly limited so I'm not aware of other possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the column to XML (or change it in the table to XML) and shred the xml on `//*` to get all nodes in a table. Then you can use `for xml path` to concat the values back together.

```sql
select (
       select ' '+X.N.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)')
       from (select cast(T.XMLCol as xml)) as T1(XMLCol)
         cross apply T1.XMLCol.nodes('//*') as X(N)
       for xml path(''), type
       ).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'varchar(max)')
from T
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aa842/1)