# Retrieve (Shredding) Multiple Values in SQL Server into same cell (row/ column intersection) in table from XML data column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a table (T) with an xml data column (XMLcol) and an ID column.

===========================

Following is the XML data:

```
"( <RootNode>    
<Node1>    
<Line_id_Node>1 </Line_id_Node>    
<A>    
<B>    
<D>Val1 </D>    
</B>    
<B>    
<D>Val2 </D>    
</B>    
<B>    
<D>Val3 </D>    
</B>    
</A>    
</Node1>


<Node1>    
<Line_id_Node> 2 </Line_id_Node>    
<A>    
<B>    
<D>Val4 </D>    
</B>    
<B>    
<D>Val2 </D>    
</B>    
</A>    
</Node1>


<Node1>    
<Line_id_Node> 3 </Line_id_Node>    
<A>    
<B>    
<D>Val5 </D>    
</B>    
</A>    
</Node1>    
</RootNode>)"
```

Expected O/P:

```
-------------------------------------------------
Line_id_Node                Column_D
-------------------------------------------------
1                           val1, val2, val3
2                           val4, val2
3                           val5
```

I want to get all the three values above in a SINGLE Cell. Tried cross apply, creating variable etc. but didn't nail a proper syntax.

If you can at least give an example of how to concatenate values in similar nodes with XML, that would also help. I want something that will act in the same way as we use ...STUFF with FOR XML PATH ( for comma separated output).

Should we use an @XMLhandle,

```
sp_xml_preparedocument

@XMLDocument, 

sp_xml_removedocument
```

?? Any help will be highly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Got this link- Let me know if you a different approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293817/retrieving-multiple-xml-child-node-values

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (id int, XMLcol xml)
INSERT @T VALUES
(1,'<C><D>Val1 </D></C><C><D>Val2 </D></C><C><D>Val3 </D></C>'),
(2,'<C><D>Val4 </D></C><C><D>Val5 </D></C><C><D>Val6 </D></C>')

SELECT id,(
  SELECT STUFF((SELECT ','+v.value('D[1]','varchar(max)')
  FROM @T
  CROSS APPLY XMLCol.nodes('C') x1(v)
  WHERE id = t.id
  FOR XML PATH('')
  ),1,1,'')
)
FROM @T t

--------------------
id  (No column name)
1   Val1 ,Val2 ,Val3 
2   Val4 ,Val5 ,Val6
```

Comment: Thanks Anon. I tried to modify the code but Stackoverflow does not allow me to paste the corrected HTML OR I'm not sure how to use Stackoverflow. It shows the values of the HTML only. The line_id_node values are 1,2,3. and expected output is shown in code block.