# how to retrieve data from xml when i have multiple nodes in sql

Tags: sql, xml

I want to retrieve the data based on equaling to `resourceID` 
,I have writtten below query

```
SELECT t.* FROM customerservice_store t WHERE 
existsNode(t.RESPONSE,'/customerDetailsResponse/resources/physicalDevice/@resourceId="bharath"','xmlns="http://sso.message.upc.com"') ='1';

SELECT t.* FROM customerservice_store t WHERE
existsNode(t.RESPONSE,'/customerDetailsResponse/resources/physicalDevice/@resourceId="bharath"','xmlns="http://sso.message.upc.com"') ='1';
```

Comment: Have you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293817/retrieving-multiple-xml-child-node-values ?

Comment: Please tag with the actual RDBMS (product and version), please add a sample for input and expected outoput and please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `existsNode` seems to be Oracle... Anyway - by guessing - I get the feeling, that you are not looking for the existance of your resourceID **anywhere**, but you rather want to find the node, where the `@resourceId` equals a given value. Read about `XQuery predicates`. You might try something like `..... /physicalDevice[@resourceId="xyz"]/ ...`